# Change GMT to EST time in Java 6

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a GMT time zone from other server to EST considering day light saving to display the correct date but not able to do.

The GMT time format is coming in json `String` as `"yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss 'Z'"`. To this format we are setting time zone as EST but not getting correct result.

Example - date coming as `"2020-06-02T03:53:57Z"` , while the correct date in EST when created was `"2020-06-01T11:53:57Z"`.

Comment: Do you have to use Java 6? There is a [backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) for the modern datetime API `java.time` which was introduced in Java 8. The outdated `java.util.Date` & Co should be avoided whenever possible. The problem here looks like a time zone or offset conversion, is EST = UTC+8?

Comment: The "EST" time zone in Java doesn't observe DST. Use "America/New_York". See http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID

Answer (score 0):

To convert between two explicit time zones, specify those time zones on the `SimpleDateFormat` objects used to parse and re-format the date string.

```java
String input = "2020-06-02T03:53:57Z";

SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

*Output*

```
2020-06-01 23:53:57 EDT
```

As you can see, in June, the time zone is `EDT`, not `EST`, and it is certainly not `Z`, aka `UTC`.